# Typescript array randomly becomes undefined

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to get data from my webservice into an array of my custom type (both models match, I have checked that)

The object itself  `people` is defined and initialised as a black array of type `Person`.

However when making the subscribe call the array is now undefined.

This was working, I'm not actually sure why it stopped

Declaration

```
  people: Person[] = [];
```

Subscription

```
getPeople() {
    this.isLoading$.next(true);
    this.PeopleService.GetAll().subscribe(
      o => {
        if (o) {
          this.people = o;
        }
        else {
          this.people = [];
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        this.isLoading$.next(false);
      }
    );
  }
```

Before the method, `this.people` is defined as `Array[0]`

When in the `getPeople` method, `this.people` is undefined.
`o` is defined and has data.

> UPDATE 1 10:41 2019/05/03

I noticed the following when debugging

[image: Console]

could this be the cause, if so why? I've been writing all my methods like this and none have ever given me this issue

Comment: how do you invoke the `getPeople` method?

Comment: on the constructor I call ```this.getPeople()```

Comment: Try this, In case of error, put this.people = []; also. the problem is, in error section you are not handling error. make sure that the api call is working currectly

Comment: @Darkestlyrics please provide enough code so that the problem was more apparent. At the moment what you claim - is impossible

Comment: @zerkms I seem to have stumbled onto why, posting the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you are using the debugger/breakpoints inside your IDE to check the value. I also guess you are compiling your typescript to es5. Another guess is that the sourcemaps are not loading inside your debugger environment.

All this combined makes a nice incoherent mess for you.

What typescript does under the hood with the arrow function notation `() => {}`, is set a `_this = this` before the arrow, and change the function to `function() {}`, which will have a new `this` context. This happens when you compile to a version that does not support the arrow notation.

If you actually do `console.log(this.people)` instead of setting a breakpoint, it will output the correct/expected value. This is compiled to `console.log(_this.people)` to the `this` of the outer scope. Does that make sense?

Anyways, you should find a way to have your IDE load the sourcemaps, or use the chrome debugger which does load the correct sourcemaps, and give you a more concise picture of your code

Comment: That is interesting, I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this section

```
        o => {
        if (o) {
          this.people = o;
        }
        else {
          this.people = [];
        }
```

Changes this to be of type `SafeSubscriber` instead of the actual Component.
So by all rights, `this.people` IS undefined in that scope.

Changing it to

```
  o => (this.people = o)
```

works as expected

I'm not entirely sure why and if anyone can figure that out I'll gladly mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: That code cannot change `this`, it's impossible. Your solution is semantically identical and cannot change the observed behaviour.

Comment: @zerkms PierreDuc gives a nice explanation as to what happens.